# Why is my SQL Count Statement is counting too many times

Tags: sql

I have a query that is supposed to count how many times a user has logged into two different versions of our software based on unique session ids. My count in my outer select statement however is counting way too many times. For example I get 31000 sessions for one user which is incorrect. It should be something more like 40. Why is this happening?

```
SELECT X.FirstName, X.LastName, X.CompanyName, X.AQ8Sessions, AQ360Sessions = COUNT(RRUI.SessionId)
 FROM(
    SELECT RRUI.UserId, RRUI.FirstName, RRUI.LastName, RRUI.CompanyName, COUNT(distinct RRUI.SessionId) AQ8Sessions
    FROM Authentication.dbo.RegReportUserInfo RRUI
    INNER JOIN Authentication.dbo.RegReportSessions RRS
        ON RRUI.SessionId = RRS.SessionId
    INNER JOIN WebCatalog.Published.People P
        ON P.PKey = RRUI.UserId
    WHERE RRUI.ClientType = 'aq8' AND RRS.ExpiresAt <= '2013-11-24 23:59:59.999'
        AND RRS.ExpiresAt >= '2013-11-18 00:00:00.000' AND RRUI.CompanyName NOT LIKE 'AutoQuotes%'
        AND P.EMail NOT LIKE '%@aqnet.com'
    GROUP BY RRUI.FirstName, RRUI.LastName, RRUI.CompanyName, RRUI.UserId
) X
INNER JOIN Authentication.dbo.RegReportSessions RRS
    ON RRS.UserId = X.UserId
    AND RRS.ExpiresAt <= '2013-11-24 23:59:59.999'
    AND RRS.ExpiresAt >= '2013-11-18 00:00:00.000'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Authentication.dbo.RegReportUserInfo RRUI
    ON X.UserId = RRUI.UserId AND RRUI.ClientType = 'aq360'
GROUP BY X.FirstName, X.LastName, X.CompanyName, X.AQ8Sessions
ORDER BY X.AQ8Sessions DESC, COUNT(RRUI.SessionId) DESC
```

Comment: Is there meant to be some association between `RegReportUserInfo` and `RegReportUserSessions`? Because at the moment, *every* matching row from one of them will be paired with *every* matching row from the other.

Comment: Please show us the table definitions, including keys.

Comment: INNER JOIN Authentication.dbo.RegReportSessions RRS
        ON RRUI.SessionId = RRS.SessionId and RRUI.UserId = RRS.UserId

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure without seeing the data but I expect one or both of these will fix it:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT RRUI.SessionId)
```

and / or

```
INNER JOIN Authentication.dbo.RegReportUserInfo
```

where you had

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Authentication.dbo.RegReportUserInfo
```

Comment: I did not mean to include distinct actually in the second part, SessionIDs are unique and I need the left outer join since some of the entries in the first selection may not have an AQ360 session. Multiple Session IDs can have the same userid and each session id only has one client type and one expires at date. Each UserID only has one firstname, lastname, email, and companyname.